# Query about Timestamp

Tags: mysql, node.js

We have a timestamp in our database which looks like this -

```
"2018-04-10T11:52:12.000Z"
```

And our input from the datetimepicker is like this -

```
 fromDate: "Mon Apr 02 2018 10:25:55 GMT+0530 (IST)"
```

So to convert it to the database format we do this in our node.js file -

```
var nowFromDate = datetime.create(fromDate);
var fromDATE = nowFromDate.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');

o/p - fromDATE = 2018-04-02 10:25:55
```

And we compare the date and retrieve the value from the database.

However, it is only comparing in the database with respect to date and not time. How to alter to match the database timestamp

Comment: Thank you .... but i have done the required changes and now its working.... i changed to var fromDATE = nowFromDate.format('Y-m-dT H:M:S.000Z');

Comment: Please provide an answer, and then accept it, or otherwise delete the question

Comment: i provided the answer...is there any other way to answer and  to accept it  ?